# How to render observed data to individual views, when the data are models

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, data-structures

I have been building an app in SwiftUI + firebase that has a social media part, where just like on twitter users can see posts and interact with them.
I am using a PostModel to view the posts, and since they are structs, I cannot make them ObservableObjects.
I have the PostViewModel that retrieves an array of PostModel from the database, which it listens to.
In my FeedView, I have a foreach loop that goes through that array and renders the data in PostRowView vertically stacked. My problem is, that the like/comment/repost functionalities are within this PostRowView. And since the posts are structs, I can only pass them as state objects. Which means that when I like a post, I will make the change in the database, but it will not appear on the UI.
BTW, the number of likes and the like icon are supposed to change. The like icon gets filled if the current connected user's id is within the array of users that liked the post (array available in the PostModel) and the number of people that liked is the count of that array.
What changes do I need to make to the code /data structure to make this work ?

I tried to render the posts on the UI in a way that they are synced with the database, but I am struggling since the structs aren't observable objects.